# Chrome on iOS - orientation change

Tags: google-chrome, orientation, mobile-safari, viewport, device-orientation

I'm working on a mobile site and we have a small problem in Chrome on iOS:

If you open the site in portrait mode and zoom in and out and then change orientation you get this view:

[image: Black space to the right shouldn't be there]

Ideally the website should fit the entire viewport.

Has anyone tried anything this? I only experience it after zooming - otherwise it works fine.

This is my meta viewport tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">`

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Do you have a better demo that I can try out?  I tried mine at http://jsbin.com/uVeSUbi/1 and it scales it up on orientation change.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to pay attention, that I've faced this bug lately and in my case the issuer was "user-scalable=no" + "width=XYpx".

Removing "user-scalable" helps, but from other side it allows us to scale a website.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the orientation to landscape, the device width will change to 480 instead of 320. So to automatically determine width with respect to orientation you can write `<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">` instead of `<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">`. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) page fore more information.

Comment: We need the page to have a fixed viewport of 320 regardless of orientation. This works fine in Safari on iOS and on Android - it is only in Chrome on iOS we experience this. Thanks for the help though :-)